# Trying to get LaTeX work with Anki

Tags: installing, mac, anki

I'm trying to get LaTeX working on Anki.  I am the only admin on my system but when I try and run the terminal command "`tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install dvipng`" I get an error saying I need to run the program as an admin. I am the admin! How do I run this program?

PS:  Due to lack of reputation, I am unable to vote or bump any existing material, so I am asking a new question.  The comment to the linked top answer below  is identical to my query, hence the identical text.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-can-i-get-latex-working-on-anki/21799#21799?newreg=5818a55a8fb146a2816064aaaa6365e9

PPS:  Crossposted from Apple StackExchange because I wasn't sure which forum was more suitable.

Answer (score 8):

http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#installing-and-assumed-knowledge

> Anki’s LaTeX support is not turn-key: it is assumed that you know how to use LaTeX already, and that you have it installed. If you have
>   no experience with LaTeX, please consult one of the many guides
>   available on the internet. If you are having trouble with markup,
>   please ask on a LaTeX forum.
>
> To install LaTeX, on Windows use MiKTeX; on OSX use MacTex, and on
>   Linux use your distro’s package manager. Dvipng must also be
>   installed.
>
> Note On Windows, go to Settings in MikTek’s maintenance window, and
>   make sure "Install missing packages on the fly" is set to "No", not to
>   "Ask me first". If you continue to have difficulties, one user
>   reported that running Anki as an administrator until all the packages
>   were fetched helped.
>
> > Note On OSX, LaTeX has only been tested with MacTex and BasicTex. If
> >     you use BasicTex, you need to install dvipng separately, with the
> >     following command:
> >
> > > **sudo tlmgr update --self; sudo tlmgr install dvipng**
> >
> > The command may not be on the path, so you may need to provide the
> >     full path, eg /usr/local/texlive/2014basic/bin/x86_64-darwin/tlmgr.
>
> Note If you are not using the above LaTeX packages, you will need to
>   use the "edit LaTeX" add-on to specify the full path to latex and
>   dvipng.

Superuser access needed, not just admin.