# Using latex tikz package alongside anki version 23.12.1

Tags: tikz-pgf, anki

### Summary of the problem

I've been attempting to get the latex tikz package working alongside my
anki version (23.12.1) without success. I've also posted about this problem [directly to the anki forum](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/using-latex-tikz-package-with-anki-version-23-12-1/41580).
I'm doing this (*working with tikz*) to include drawing that are illustrative to my flashcard notes
in anki.

I use a markdown convertion notetaking process, that is described and documented in
[github dot com slash lervag slash apy](https://github.com/lervag/apy), but for most part this is exactly the same as adding the notes directly with the anki editor.
This is the particular drawing that I've been trying to configure.

```
[latex]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Draw the circles
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (3);
  % Add lines to labels
  \draw[->, thick] (0,0.2) -- (4,0.2) node[right] {Identity};
  \draw[->, thick] (0,1.5) -- (4,1.5) node[right] {Processes};
  \draw[->, thick] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5) node[right] {outcomes};
\end{tikzpicture}
[\latex]
```

I had thought that as soon as I added the *tikz* package to the premable that
the problem would resolve itself. This is the updated preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx} % added line for tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % added to color rows
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

- [X] I also have the "create scalable images with dvisvgm" checked off.

*HOWEVER*, this doesn't seem to be the case and instead the text is rendered as
the plaintext coding directly into the flashcard.

### Research into a solution

I've looked up other posts on the topic, and couldn't find anything specifically
geared towards tikz but instead found [an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472989/how-do-you-get-anki-2-1-to-work-with-xetex-edit-latex-build-process?newreg=fba9dc107eb64b349659ab281d80f68d) focused on getting the latex working within anki.

### Things That I've Tried

I installed the `Edit latex build process` that is also described in the
[anki webseite documentation](https://docs.ankiweb.net/math.html#latex), and re-configured the build process to include `pdflatex`, which is in my path,
and which I use for testing tex documents in vim with the command,

`autocmd BufWritePost *.tex execute "!pdflatex --shell-escape -output-directory=/tmp/  %"`

, and the configuration in the `Edit latex build process` is as follows:

```
{
    "pngCommands": [
        [
            "latex",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "tmp.tex"
        ],
        [
            "dvipng",
            "-D",
            "200",
            "-T",
            "tight",
            "tmp.dvi",
            "-o",
            "tmp.png"
        ]
    ],
    "svgCommands": [
        [
            "pdflatex",
            "-output-format=dvi",
            "-shell-escape",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "tmp.tex"
        ],
        [
            "dvisvgm",
            "--no-fonts",
            "-Z",
            "2",
            "tmp.dvi",
            "-o",
            "tmp.svg"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I've noticed that when the command doesn't execute with success the error is rendered in place of the image, since this occurred a few times when I attempted the process
of adding latex sections in the anki editor.

Comment: Welcome. // Is this also from you: https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/using-latex-tikz-package-with-anki-version-23-12-1/41580 ?

Comment: A bypass can be to create a separate image, e.g. via class standalone (see details in the manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone, or use your TEX-systems features to do so) . Once you have it, include the image rather than LaTeX code.

Comment: @MS-SPO, yeap that was me, lol

Comment: Will be better if you'd mention that at the beginning of your question. Please EDIT and add. Thank you

Comment: got a change to update the post as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tikz in Anki directly seems to be a tedious process as far as configration is concerned. So let's spell out the suggestion I made in a [comment: use standalone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/711441/using-latex-tikz-package-alongside-anki-version-23-12-1#comment1768225_711441), which I consider a powerful bypass, if not a powerful solution.

#### Your drawing with Latex

So I:

- took your code
- embeded it as needed
- `\documentclass{standalone}`
- replaced arrow-tips
- compile e.g. `ankiTikz.tex` into `ankiTikz.pdf`

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[    % self-defined styles
    >={Stealth},        % using some nicer arrow tips
]
  % Draw the circles
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (3);
  % Add lines to labels
  \draw[->, thick] (0,0.2) -- (4,0.2) node[right] {Identity};
  \draw[->, thick] (0,1.5) -- (4,1.5) node[right] {Processes};
  \draw[->, thick] (0,2.5) -- (4,2.5) node[right] {outcomes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

#### Bitmap conversion

Don't know if you can include a pdf with an Anki-card. However, bitmaps you can right away, as you probably have done already many times.

So how to convert the `.pdf` into a `bitmap`?

The trick of the trade is using free [image-magick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). Once installed just type on your command line:

```
magick -density 200 -units PixelsPerInch ankiTikz.pdf ankiTikz.png
```

which created the posted bitmap.

As the [manual for class standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) tells you in ch. `5.6 Conversion to images` you can also automate that step directly in Latex, i.e. compile and get the bitmap in one go.

#### In other words ...

you can stop configuring Anki and start creating tons of useful drawings instead, right away.