# How to get Anki working with TikZ-based packages in 2024?

Tags: chemfig, shell-escape, anki

I want to learn the LaTeX language to study chemistry with chemfig package and make Anki flashcards. The problem is that I am unable to make it work with Anki (normal LaTeX works fine)

I tried these kinds of tutorials but somes instructions dont work :

[How to get Anki working with TikZ-based packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320139/how-to-get-anki-working-with-tikz-based-packages)

or

http://pastebin.com/raw/mJj7gTQ7

the problem is the same mentionned in the first tutorial, and if I activate the option "create adjustable images with dvisgvm"

I get that error message :

```
General formula of an aldehydeProblem running pdflatex⁩.
generated file : ⁨C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\anki_temp\tmp.tex⁩
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>

(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cl
s
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))))

(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.cf
g) (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
Executing command:
magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch tmp.pdf  -quality 90 tmp.png


Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape
(standalone)              is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').

) (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/standalone\standalone.st
y (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/currfile\currfile.sty
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
```

Comment: Welcome. // Here was a similar question, for which I proposed a bypass solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713122/245790 . Anki seems to be troublesome to set up with Latex, while said solution works right away (Tikz image, pdf, convert to bitmap, include in Anki - fast to do, lengthy to write)

Comment: as shown in the error you show you need   `pdflatex -shell-escape`  but your log shows you did not do that: `restricted \write18 enabled`

Comment: Okay, but how can I activate -shell-escape ?